# Meteor MongoDB bulk multiplication of prices into 2 decimal places only

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to bulk update prices of a "product" collection.
Basically to divide them by a specific number.

This worked:

```
Products.update({status:'active'}, {$mul: {price:(1/1.07)}}, {multi:true});
```

However, this results into prices that looks like 123.444576357564932342 in the database. Which looks a bit ugly to me.

Is there anyway to do a toFixed(2) somewhere in the $mul operation?

Schema of Product:

```
Schema.product = new SimpleSchema({
    productId: {
        type: Number,
        optional: true
    },

    title: {
        type: String
    },

    name: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },

    price: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true
    },

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({
  status: "active"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      price: { $round: [ { $multiply: [ "$price", { $divide: [ 1, 1.07 ] } ] }, 2 ] }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cWgGzDoYvZ6)

Comment: when trying the above in my Meteor app, I get this error "Error: When the modifier option is true, all validation object keys must be operators. Did you forget `$set`?"  Do u have any idea?